# What is the name of the technique where quotation marks are not closed but reopened to indicate a break in speech

Tags: technique, formatting, punctuation

> The wizard slid the application over to the goblin.
>
> "I'm afraid, Mister Barnes, we cannot accept your letter of resignation at present. You are simply too ugly to qualify for an exit scheme, and you are doomed to remain at this company indefinite**ly.**
>
> **"Fo**rtunately for you, you have the ability to screw up so badly that we will be forced to fire you. You will also be summarily executed, but still..."

I have emphasized the section before and after in boldface. The same person continues talking, with additional opening speech marks with no closing speech marks. What can I use to refer to this?

Answer (score 15):

This is called the multi-paragraph quotation rule;

see here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96608/why-does-the-multi-paragraph-quotation-rule-exist

Also read the top accepted answer there, for an explanation as to why we do it that way (so we don't have to re-identify who is speaking for every new paragraph).